# How i can display image in symbian c++

Tags: c++, symbian

Hi i'm new in symbian c++ and sdk 5th, I use carbide c++ how i can display some image? (.bmp extension for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps have a look into the DrawBitmap and BitBit functions.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [CImageDisplay API](http://library.forum.nokia.com/topic/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/reference/reference-cpp/Imaging_Frameworks/CImageDisplayClass.html).